# Android Google Fit get basic info (Gender, Height, Weight)

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have been working on Google fit integration for Android since a couple of days and got stuck at a point. I need to get height, weight and gender data from google fit. I could successfully get the height and weight of the user from google fit by making a query using the following data types

```
 DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                               .read(DataType.TYPE_WEIGHT)
                               .read(DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT)
                               .setLimit(1)
                               .setTimeRange(1, currentTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                               .build();
```

But failed to get the details of the user's gender. I'm wasting a huge time in figuring this out. I would like to at least know that getting gender from Google fit is not possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid google don't provide pre defined `DataType` for gender as of now. It might possible they provide support in upcoming updates.
There are four types of `fields` for all Google Fit data types. 
You can check the data types list [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/data-type-field-names) without investing lot of time in research.

*I would like to at least know that getting gender from Google fit is not possible.*

This is achievable through `Custom data types`.

1. Build a request to for your custom data type
2. With Google API client object invoke the Config API
3. Check the result asynchronously

Below a sample code for your reference :

```
    GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
     .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
     ... .build();
     client.connect();

     PendingResult<DataTypeResult> pendingResult = Fitness.ConfigApi.readDataType(
         client, "com.example.my_custom_data_type");

     DataTypeResult dataTypeResult = pendingResult.await();
     DataType dataType = dataTypeResult.getDataType();
```

Comment: Hey, what I understood is that you are suggesting me to build a custom data type and write the gender to that data type and read it from that when required.

Comment: Exactly, you just have to keep certain rules in mind while creating one.

Comment: @Anurag, could you please explain it briefly? What will i write instead of "com.example.my_custom_data_type" to retrieve gender and dob from google fit..